# Internet Explorer COM objects stop working during runtime

Tags: internet-explorer, com, crash, autoit

My referenced Internet Explorer COM object works for some time and then suddenly stops at different places (while accessing COM objects or their properties) and varying errors.

The same code runs hundreds of times, then suddenly reports a COM error. Usually, all following COM calls fail too. I use AutoIt and the IE.au3 UDF. I designed a small test script that starts a new browser instance, connects to it, loads `www.leo.org` and then gets the URL of an arbitrary link in a loop, until an error occurs.

Is it a bug? I would appreciate if someone would test the script. This also occurs when accessing Microsoft Excel COM object. On Windows 7 all runs cancel between 3300 and 4200 Loops. But on Windows 10 it exceeded 10k loops.

```
#include <IE.au3>

;;  sMode choices
;;      "chain"    : access a long com path
;;      "separate" : split path and access com objects one by one $sMode = "chain"

_IEErrorHandlerRegister()

Switch $sMode Then
    Case "chain"
        Local $iCount = 0
        Local $oIE = ObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Local $s = ""
        Local $err = Null

        $oIE.Visible = True
        $oIE.Navigate("www.leo.org")
        While StringLower($oIE.readystate) <> "complete" And $oIE.readystate <> 4
            Sleep(500)
        WEnd
        While StringLower($oIE.document.readystate) <> "complete" And $oIE.readystate <> 4
            Sleep(500)
        WEnd

        While True
            $iCount += 1
            $s = $oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a") (2).href
            $err = @error
            ConsoleWrite("" & $iCount & ". " & $s & " - " & $err & @CRLF)
            If $err Then ExitLoop
            Sleep(150)
        WEnd
EndSwitch
```

[image]

Comment: Try autoit [com error handler](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ObjEvent.htm) (although I am not sure if that is a COM error).

Comment: Try doing request/response with [winhttp object](https://beamtic.com/http-requests-autoit) instead and then parse your html like this: `$ohtml = ObjCreate('HTMLFILE')
$ohtml.body.innerHTML = "<p>WhatEver</p>"

ConsoleWrite($ohtml.body.innerTEXT & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite($ohtml.body.innerHTML & @CRLF)`

Comment: Also I believe it should be `$oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].href` or `$oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a").item(3).href` instead of `$oIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(2).href` ? Autoit uses `[]` to access array elements, not `()`. Although it appears to work anyways, weird?

Comment: garbb Thank you very much for your quick answers and your invested time! Regarding your points: 
a) I use the default COM error handler from IE.au3 that takes care for printing out the ComErrorObject's information. It is registered by _IEErrorHandlerRegister() in line 8. However, I wonder why no com error is thrown here, but an AutoIt Error trying to access a missing com object property. Guess it's in the nature of this "bug"? Other runs cancel with com errors like -2147352568 "wrong variable type" (because no valid obj-type is returned from com interface, I assume).

Comment: b) Getting the html-Code in another way does not help. The website is internally modified by javascript, according to response data from AJAX calls. So I need to access the current DOM objects. Apart from that, it does not fix my access problem on COM objects. The calls work, until suddenly the very same calls stop working during runtime. And just ignoring does not work, as more and more com error occur after the first one.

Comment: c) I guess it is part of the mapping. In Javascript you use [2] to access the third item of the element list. In AutoIt you use [2] to access the third array item. But COM objects are pointers and nested path elements seem to be handled like functions. That's why I have to used parentheses to access items of a com array from AutoIt.

Comment: News: I have tried to compile and run the script. Both seem to be successful, the script runs continuously - now at 5.3k loops. It's not a 100% proof, but since the test script never exceeded 4300 Loops when run from SciTE, it seems not to Crash so quickly.